# How to change linestyle from a graphics into a movieclip dynamically?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I draw a line using "graphics.lineTo" into a movieclip and i need to change my linestyle if the user ask for that throw a button in runtime. I can change the color, but i can't change the linestyle...

Is there someway to change it?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot change the line style once the line has been drawn. You need to record yourself the steps that produce the graphics (moveTo, lineTo, lineStyle, beginFill, etc.) and recreate it when the user changes the line style.